# How can I reverse a string in Batch?

Tags: string, batch-file, reverse

I found this solution for reversing strings that worked before, but not any more for some reason:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0
:LOOP
call set tmpa=%%advanced:~%num%,1%%%
set /a num+=1
if not "%tmpa%" equ "" (
set string1=%tmpa%%string1%
goto LOOP
)
```

My message that I receive is:

```
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I simply need to reverse the string in the variable `%advanced%` and output it to `%string1%`.

If reversing strings can be done in one line, that would be super helpful in the project I am working on. If it can be done without the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, that would be even more helpful but I doubt it is be possible.

Comment: How long is your input string? Batch strings can only be 8192 characters long, and if you're getting an error saying that your input line is too long, you're going to have problems.

Comment: There may be some characters in your string that are breaking the code, like `%` or `!` or `)` or `&`.

Comment: Your code enables delayed expansion, but then does not use it. Your use of CALL with double percents is much slower then using delayed expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said it first worked and later not anymore; I think simply clearing variable `string1` will do the trick. Your code should work as is.

Next, you do not need to enable delayed expansion as you are not using it (`!!` expansion) anyway.

Finally, instead of asking whether `tmpa` is empty, you could query whether it is defined (but this is a matter of taste though).

```
set string1=
set num=0
:LOOP
call set tmpa=%%advanced:~%num%,1%%%
set /a num+=1
if defined tmpa (
    set string1=%tmpa%%string1%
    goto :LOOP
)
```

Answer (score 3):

In this way it works if you change to `set string1=!tmpa!!string1!`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "advanced=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!"

set "num=0"
:LOOP
call set "tmpa=%%advanced:~%num%,1%%%"
set /a num+=1
if not "%tmpa%" equ "" (
  set "string1=!tmpa!!string1!"
  goto LOOP
)
echo !string1!
endlocal
```

Another way a bit faster:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "advanced=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
echo %advanced%>"%tmp%\alpha.tmp"

for %%l in ("%tmp%\alpha.tmp") do set /a len=%%~zl
set /a len-=2

set "reverse="
set "char="
for /l %%i in (0,1,%len%) do (
  for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("%tmp%\alpha.tmp") do (
    set "char=%%a"
    set "reverse=!char:~%%i,1!!reverse!"
  )
)
del "%tmp%\alpha.tmp"
echo !reverse!
endlocal
```

Comment: Why there is an exclamation mark at the end of the string?
"advanced=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!"

Answer (score 3):

Another way using a BAT/VBS :

```
@echo off
set "advanced=1234567890"

echo WScript.Echo StrReverse("%advanced%"^) >reverse.vbs

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo reverse.vbs') do set "$reversed=%%a"
>nul del reverse.vbs

echo reversed string --^> %$reversed%
```

Answer (score 1):

To reverse a string or file contents:

```
REM eg. set string/content to file
set /p="Hello, world!"> test
certutil -encodehex -f test temp 4

REM reverse file contents
set rev=
(for /f "delims=" %i in (temp) do for %j in (%i) do set rev=%j !rev!)
set /p="%rev:~0,-6%">temp
certutil -decodehex temp out.txt

REM view content
more out.txt
```

Tested in Win 10 CMD